# Inspect element, copy certain divs?

Tags: html, google-chrome, element, inspect

first of all: Sorry for my bad english ^^.
My Question is: is there any oppertunity to copy certain divs by using Inspect elements? I especially want to copy all of these kind of divisions.. or is there an option or code that i can post in the console so every division etc. expect the divisions i need, get deleted?

I am happy for every answer!
Best regards

Comment: Hi Kulusbe762, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you need to download page web as completed page in folder

and then try open this folder in your text editor

and get what you want :)

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the answer! But i am like an amateur, so i dont really know what you exactly meant. How can i download this thing you mentioned?

Comment: just go to the page you want and click right click in page and then you see menu
and you see first choose 'Save Page As...' click on it and save file in your pc